# How much can I parse the results of an A/B test without breaking the assumptions in the test?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Let's say I run an A/B experiment on 1,000 rats. I give one group regular food and the other a special type of food that should help their cognition and I compare their performance at mazes.

Imagine that the difference in time to complete the maze is statistically significant (`alpha < 0.01`), my experiment had power greater than `.8` and the confidence interval does not inclued `0`.

I want to understand how this affects just male rats. I'd like to ignore all the non-male subjects and see if the result is statistically significant.

I find that there is a significant difference. Can I claim those results, despite  bias I may have introduced?